# Loading a JAR file from a URL

Tags: java, http, jar, header

How can I load a JAR file from a URL in Java while making the request for the file seem legit by adding necessary HTTP Headers into the request.

The only way I know how to maintain the loaded JAR file at the moment is to use `ClassLoader`.

I think I nailed this question pretty good (Or so it seems that way in my head!) but if anyone needs me to provide more information before they can help me, be sure to ask me.

Comment: `make the request ... seem legit`, that seems to imply that you're trying to access something you wouldn't normally get access to. Can you explain more what you want to achieve? Do you want to load/instantiate the classes, or just have the file available in memory?

Comment: No, you "normally" have full access to it via your browser. I just want to emulate a browser (By providing HTTP headers.) when loading a JAR file via Java. Also, yes I want to be able to load the classes in the JAR file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:  http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html

Comment: I already used the `URLClassLoader` with the `ClassLoader` before. However (As far as I know!) it's not possible to add HTTP Headers to the request using A `URLClassLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to pass specific HTTP headers by passing a custom [`URLStreamHandlerFactory`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandlerFactory.html) in a [`URLClassLoader` constructor](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL[],%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory%29).

Note that this is slightly different from creating the `URLClassLoader` using `newInstance` as it doesn't use `checkPackageAccess` from the `SecurityManager` (so you might have to do that yourself).

Alternatively, perhaps [jcloader](http://jcloader.sourceforge.net/) could be of interest (but I haven't tried it): it might be easier to make a more traditional HTTP request (without using a `URLStreamHandlerFactory`), potentially with the HTTP headers you want, and then load the result using one of its classloaders (as an `InputStream` or something similar).

(There are of course other security implications for loading a jar file from a remote source, as you may need to verify you trust the integrity of this file.)